# preg_replace issue on multiple

Tags: php, regex, loops, preg-replace, preg-match

Currently I'm getting this result https://puu.sh/zvWLl/1db4614184.png
from this set of code:

```
$CheckArrays = [
"QUOTE" => "/\[quote=?(.*)\](.*)\[\/quote\]/",
"BOLD" => "/\[b\](.*)\[\/b\]/",
"ITALIC" => "/\[i\](.*)\[\/i\]/",
];

$FanceString = $UglyString;

// QUOTES
do {
    $FanceString = preg_replace_callback(
        $CheckArrays['QUOTE'],
        function($match) {
            if (is_numeric($match[1])) {
                $TPID = GetThreadPoster($match[1]);
                $TPUN = GetUsernameS($TPID);
                $statement = ('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">'.$match[2].'<br>- <b>'.$TPUN.'</b></div></div>');
            } elseif (!is_numeric($match[1])) {
                $statement = ('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">'.$match[2].'</div></div>');
            }
            return $statement;
        },
        $FanceString,
        -1,
        $count
    );
} while ($count > 0);
```

With my test string being:

```
[quote=82][quote=76]Isn't that the true ultimate question?[/quote]
[b]I suppose, if that [b]test[/b] makes you feel better[/b][/quote]


This is a test
```

Basically, this is what I'm attempting to achieve.. https://puu.sh/zvWVs/c27663e0ac.png

Comment: Can't you use a proper BBCode parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll present my solution here but you should really use a parser instead. For your specific situation, you could use a recursive approach:

```
\[b[^][]*\]
(?:[^][]*|(?R))*
\[/b\]
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/YR4WNt/1).

---

The `PHP` code would be:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
[quote=82][quote=76]Isn't that the true ultimate question?[/quote]
[b]I suppose, if that [b]test[/b] makes you feel better[/b][/quote]


This is a test
DATA;

$outer = '~
                \[b[^][]*\]
                (?:[^][]*|(?R))*
                \[/b\]
                ~x';

$inner = '~\[/?[^][]*\]~';
$data = preg_replace_callback(
    $outer,
    function($match) use ($inner) {
        return "<strong>" . preg_replace($inner, '', $match[0]) . "</strong>";
    },
    $data);

echo $data;
?>
```

Which yields

```
[quote=82][quote=76]Isn't that the true ultimate question?[/quote]
<strong>I suppose, if that test makes you feel better</strong>[/quote]


This is a test
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I'm going to use a BBCode parser instead, but I can use this somewhere else in what I'm doing. I really appreciate it. (In all honesty, I didn't even think of using an already made bbcode parser tbh)